# Bind attribute to checkbox value Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf with Spring for a simple form submission and I want to pass the value true to my object when the checkbox is checked. This is what I have tried:

```
<form id="allowance" action="#" th:action="@{/allowance}" th:object="${allowanceObject}" method="post">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <input type="hidden" value="on" name="_isAbroad"/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="isAbroad" /><span>Abroad</span>
        </div>
...
```

This is the object that I am passing to the model in my Spring controller:

```
public class AllowanceWrapper {

private List<Allowance> allowanceList;
private boolean isAbroad;
}
```

When I check the checkbox and hit the submit button the attribute is still not set on true. Do you have any ideas what could be wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: you need to avoid start with `is` in `boolean` value,since `isXXX` is equal to `getXXX` in `boolean` value